# Eclipse cannot find Twitter class in twitter4j

Tags: eclipse, jar

I'm using the twitter4j 2.1.11 jar, but Eclipse doesn't seem to be able to find classes within it. I added the jar as a referenced library, but get `Twitter cannot be resolved to a type` when trying to use it. I can add imports like `import twitter4j.*` but not `import twitter4j.Twitter`.

I can tell the class is available as it is present when I open the jar in an archive viewer. How can I get Eclipse to behave?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem I was having was that I was importing the wrong archive, specifically the sources archive rather than the one found in /lib of the twitter4j download.

Comment: I had forgotten about this question. I'd like to think SO isn't purely about rep gain though.